# Would setting script-src 'self' and frame-src 'unsafe-inline' conflict with each other?

Tags: http, http-headers, content-security-policy

If I have a content-security-policy that looks like this:

```
default-src 'self'
script-src 'self'
frame-src 'unsafe-inline'
```

And I have a web page that has a frame inside it, where the frame that points to some external source. This frame runs a script that comes from the same origin as everything else in the frame.

I don't really understand how these would interact with each other. Would my script and frame settings conflict with each other in any way, or would it be a case of the frame-src will be allowed to run the script?

Answer (score 2):

You can only set `'unsafe-inline'` in the `default-src`, `script-src` or `style-src` directives in a CSP. It is not valid in the `frame-src`, or `child-src` as `frame-src` is now deprecated.

When loading the frame you can't set any CSP restrictions on it as it will honour it's own CSP set by the host if present.